EDI translator to excel
I have this VBA code, but for some reason I can't extract the PID ITEM Description (PIDF08***GENTLE MONSTER BLCK HORNET~
Here is the code:
Sub TransformData()
    Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet
    Set wsOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW") ' Change to your sheet name
    
    Dim wsTransformed As Worksheet
    Set wsTransformed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transformed") ' Change to your sheet name
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsOriginal.Cells(wsOriginal.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim data As Variant
    data = wsOriginal.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
    
    Dim table As Variant
    ReDim table(1 To UBound(data), 1 To 30) ' Adjusted for 30 fields (added CTP fields)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    
    Dim docNum As String
    Dim dateTransmitted As String
    Dim vendorName As String
    Dim vendorAddress As String
    Dim vendorCity As String
    Dim vendorState As String
    Dim vendorZip As String
    Dim dtm010 As String
    Dim dtm001 As String
    Dim pidDescription As String
    Dim ctpValue As String
    
    ' Clear the output worksheet before writing new data
    wsTransformed.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Write column names in the first row
    wsTransformed.Range("A1").Value = "Document Number"
    wsTransformed.Range("B1").Value = "Date Transmitted"
    wsTransformed.Range("C1").Value = "Vendor Name"
    wsTransformed.Range("D1").Value = "Vendor Address"
    wsTransformed.Range("E1").Value = "Vendor City"
    wsTransformed.Range("F1").Value = "Vendor State"
    wsTransformed.Range("G1").Value = "Vendor Zip"
    wsTransformed.Range("H1").Value = "FOB"
    wsTransformed.Range("I1").Value = "DF"
    wsTransformed.Range("J1").Value = "DTM"
    wsTransformed.Range("K1").Value = "DTM Qualifier"
    wsTransformed.Range("L1").Value = "DTM Date"
    wsTransformed.Range("M1").Value = "DTM Qualifier"
    wsTransformed.Range("N1").Value = "DTM Qualifier"
    wsTransformed.Range("O1").Value = "DTM Date"
    wsTransformed.Range("P1").Value = "PO1 Item Number"
    wsTransformed.Range("Q1").Value = "PO1 Quantity"
    wsTransformed.Range("R1").Value = "Unit of Measure"
    wsTransformed.Range("S1").Value = "Price"
    wsTransformed.Range("T1").Value = "Vendor Item Number"
    wsTransformed.Range("U1").Value = "Item Type"
    wsTransformed.Range("V1").Value = "Additional Vendor Item Number"
    wsTransformed.Range("W1").Value = "Additional Item Type"
    wsTransformed.Range("X1").Value = "PID"
    wsTransformed.Range("Y1").Value = "PID Qualifier"
    wsTransformed.Range("Z1").Value = "PID Item Description"
    wsTransformed.Range("AA1").Value = "CTP Value" ' New CTP column
    wsTransformed.Range("AB1").Value = "CTP Qualifier" ' New CTP Qualifier column
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        ' Remove ~ from the data
        Dim cleanData As String
        cleanData = Replace(data(i, 1), "~", "")
        
        If InStr(cleanData, "BEG*00*SA*") > 0 Then
            docNum = Split(cleanData, "*")(3)
            dateTransmitted = Split(cleanData, "*")(5)
        ElseIf InStr(cleanData, "N1*ST*") > 0 Then
            vendorName = Split(cleanData, "*")(2)
            vendorAddress = Split(data(i + 1, 1), "*")(0)
            vendorCity = Split(data(i + 2, 1), "*")(1)
            vendorState = Split(data(i + 2, 1), "*")(2)
            vendorZip = Split(data(i + 2, 1), "*")(3)
        ElseIf InStr(cleanData, "DTM*010*") > 0 Then
            dtm010 = Split(cleanData, "*")(2)
        ElseIf InStr(cleanData, "DTM*001*") > 0 Then
            dtm001 = Split(cleanData, "*")(2)
        ElseIf InStr(cleanData, "PO1*") > 0 Then
            ' Extract PO1 details
            Dim poParts() As String
            poParts = Split(cleanData, "*")
            
            table(j, 1) = docNum
            table(j, 2) = dateTransmitted
            table(j, 3) = vendorName
            table(j, 4) = vendorAddress
            table(j, 5) = vendorCity
            table(j, 6) = vendorState
            table(j, 7) = vendorZip
            table(j, 8) = "FOB" ' Static value
            table(j, 9) = "DF" ' Static value
            table(j, 10) = "DTM" ' Static value
            table(j, 11) = "010" ' Static value
            table(j, 12) = dtm010 ' DTM date from earlier
            table(j, 13) = "DTM" ' Static value
            table(j, 14) = "001" ' Static value
            table(j, 15) = dtm001 ' DTM date from earlier
            
            ' Extract PO1 details
            If InStr(cleanData, "PO1*") > 0 Then
                ' Extract PO1 details using Split
                table(j, 16) = Split(cleanData, "*")(1) ' PO1 Item Number
                table(j, 17) = Split(cleanData, "*")(2) ' PO1 Quantity
                table(j, 18) = Split(cleanData, "*")(3) ' Unit of Measure
                table(j, 19) = Split(cleanData, "*")(4) ' Price
            End If
            
            ' Extract Vendor Item Number and Item Type safely
            Dim parts() As String
            parts = Split(cleanData, "*")
            
            If UBound(parts) >= 7 Then
                table(j, 20) = Trim(Replace(parts(7), "~", "")) ' Vendor Item Number (remove ~)
            Else
                table(j, 20) = "" ' Handle missing value
            End If
            
            If UBound(parts) >= 8 Then
                table(j, 21) = Trim(Replace(parts(8), "~", "")) ' Item Type (remove ~)
            Else
                table(j, 21) = "" ' Handle missing value
            End If
            
            If UBound(parts) >= 9 Then
                table(j, 22) = Trim(Replace(parts(9), "~", "")) ' Additional Vendor Item Number (if applicable, remove ~)
            Else
                table(j, 22) = "" ' Handle missing value
            End If
            
            If UBound(parts) >= 10 Then
                table(j, 23) = Trim(Replace(parts(10), "~", "")) ' Additional Item Type (if applicable, remove ~)
            Else
                table(j, 23) = "" ' Handle missing value
            End If
            
            ' Initialize PID description
            pidDescription = ""
            
            ' Move to the next line to look for PID*F*
            i = i + 1
            
            ' Loop to find PID*F* lines
            Do While i <= UBound(data) And InStr(data(i, 1), "PID*F*") > 0
                Dim pidParts() As String
                pidParts = Split(data(i, 1), "*")
                
                ' Check if there are enough parts to extract the description
                If UBound(pidParts) >= 4 Then
                    ' Extract the description from the 4th part (index 4)
                    pidDescription = Trim(Replace(pidParts(7), "~", "")) ' Capture description and remove ~
                End If
                
                i = i + 1 ' Move to the next line
            Loop
            
            table(j, 24) = "PID" ' Static value
            table(j, 25) = "F" ' Static value
            table(j, 26) = Trim(pidDescription) ' PID Item Description
            
            ' Check for CTP details
            If InStr(data(i, 1), "CTP**") > 0 Then
                Dim ctpParts() As String
                ctpParts = Split(data(i, 1), "*")
                
                If UBound(ctpParts) >= 2 Then
                    ctpValue = Trim(Replace(ctpParts(2), "~", "")) ' CTP Value
                    table(j, 27) = ctpValue ' Store CTP Value
                End If
                
                If UBound(ctpParts) >= 3 Then
                    table(j, 28) = Trim(Replace(ctpParts(3), "~", "")) ' CTP Qualifier
                End If
            End If
            
            j = j + 1 ' Move to the next row in the table
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Write the transformed data starting from row 2
    wsTransformed.Range("A2:AB" & j).Value = table ' Adjusted to AB for 30 columns
    
    ' Create a table from the data
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = wsTransformed.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, wsTransformed.Range("A1:AB" & j - 1), , xlYes)
    tbl.Name = "TransformedData" ' Name the table
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9" ' Optional: Set a table style
    
    ' Format column B (Date Transmitted) as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm
    wsTransformed.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
    
    ' Format columns L and O (DTM Date) as mm/dd/yyyy
    wsTransformed.Columns(12).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    wsTransformed.Columns(15).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    
    ' Autofit columns for better visibility
    wsTransformed.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub

to populate the PID Description column on my excel file.

The code uses 7 pidDescription = Trim(Replace(pidParts(7), "~", "")) but the comment says Extract the description from the 4th part (index 4)

thanks, i did that too pidDescription = Trim(Replace(pidParts(4), "~", "")). but when i run the code, the column is still blank.

If the text  PIDF08***GENTLE MONSTER BLCK HORNET is split on * then index 3 will be the description.

Its 4 actually. the data looks like this PIDF08***GENTLE MONSTER BLCK HORNET~

Hard to debug without the data but double check the AND logic here Do While i <= UBound(data) And InStr(data(i, 1), "PID*F*") > 0 . Are you trying to skip lines where InStr(data(i, 1), "PID*F*") = 0 ?

the logic should be if PIDF08***GENTLE MONSTER BLCK HORNET~ is found, it should get the GENTLE MONSTER BLCK HORNET and put it on column 26

Try revising the logic here
        ' Loop to find PID*F* lines
        Do While i <= UBound(data)
           If Left(data(i, 1), 6) = "PID*F*" Then
                Dim pidParts() As String
                pidParts = Split(data(i, 1), "*")
                
                ' Check if there are enough parts to extract the description
                If UBound(pidParts) >= 4 Then
                    ' Extract the description from the 4th part (index 4)
                    pidDescription = Trim(Replace(pidParts(7), "~", "")) ' Capture description and remove ~
                End If
                Exit Do  
            Else
                i = i + 1 ' Move to the next line
            End If
        Loop


It did work, i just revised the pidparts(7) to pidparts(5).
now my problem is the CTP, it is blank already.
' Check for CTP details
If InStr(data(i, 1), "CTP**") > 0 Then
ctpParts = Split(data(i, 1), "*")
If UBound(ctpParts) >= 2 Then
ctpValue = Trim(Replace(ctpParts(2), "~", "")) ' CTP Value
table(j, 27) = ctpValue ' Store CTP Value
end if
If UBound(ctpParts) >= 3 Then
table(j, 28) = Trim(Replace(ctpParts(3), "~", "")) ' CTP Qualifier
End If
j = j + 1 ' Move to the next row in the table
end if
next i
